# Crystal Report not showing when we try to view it while it's hosted on the live server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, crystal-reports-2008

I am facing an error with a Crystal Report.
When I put my project on local server it works fine, but when I put on the production server no errors occurs, but crystal report viewer is not showing me report.

And I am using crystal report 10.5

Comment: I'm sorry, there's not enough information here to really help.  Did you check the event log on the server?  Are you hosting the viewer ActiveX control in Internet Explorer, or is this a standalone exe?  If it's in IE, are you sure JavaScript errors aren't turned off?  really, without some indication we can be of no help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to instal [crnet11win_en](http://download.corrupteddatarecovery.com/download/crnet11win_en.exe)
crystal decision.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i dont know what is it?? Can you please explain?